# Insert a row and autofill using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which inserts a row in a spreadsheet and I want it to auto fill the formulas in the new inserted row.

Here an example of what I have in my spreadsheet.

**Edit:** In my currently spreadsheet a have 10 columns and several rows but bellow I just copied one column

```
   ColumnB
    TextA
    TextA
    TextA
    TextA
    TextB
    TextB
    TextB
    TextB
    TextC
    TextC
    TextC
    TextC
```

The following code add a new row after `TextA`, `TextB`, `TextC` and so on

```
Sub Insert()

  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim Cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row

    For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:B" & LastRow)
        If Cell.Value <> Cell.Offset(1, 0) Then
            If Cell.Value <> "" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Cell.Row + 1).Insert
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there a way to auto fill the formulas?

I thought to insert a line of code such as the following inside my loop, just after adding the new row. The problem with this is the `Range` argument. I don't know what to specify in it

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A21:J22"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: add something like range(cell,cell.offset(1,0))

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub Insert()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Assuming Row6 is the header row
LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = LastRow To 8 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2) <> "" And Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(i - 1, 2) Then
        Range(Cells(i - 1, 1), Cells(i - 1, LastCol)).Copy
        Cells(i, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, LastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know your Range you can insert any of the below methods after your 'Next Cell' statement:

```
Excel.Cells.Range("B7:B" & LastRow).Value = "=MOD(OFFSET(A7,-1,0)+ (A6<>OFFSET(A6,-1,0)),2)" 'or any function you like, e.g. '=SUM(A1+A2)'
Excel.Cells.Range("B7:B" & LastRow).Value = "0"
Excel.Cells.Range("B7:B" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "General"
Excel.Cells.Range("B7:B" & LastRow).FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:="=B6=1")
```